# ReferenceEdge Serialization error using JanusGraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I'm getting serialization errors when retrieving a list of edges from a remote JanusGraph server using Gremlin in a Java application (error message and configurations bellow).

This is the traversal that raises the error:

```
List<Edge> eList = g.E().toList();
```

Trying to get only one edge also raises an error:

```
Edge edge= g.E().next();
```

Nevertheless, when retrieving a vertex or a list of vertices, it works perfectly:

```
List<Vertex> vList = g.V().toList();
```

This is my remote-objects.yaml file:

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0,
              config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

This is the code to get the remote traversal:

```
PropertiesConfiguration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration(remote-objects.yaml);
cluster = Cluster.open(conf.getString("gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile"));
client = cluster.connect();
g = AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal().withRemote(propFileName);
```

This is the serializers in my server configuration:

```
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0, org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0, org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  # Older serialization versions for backwards compatibility:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV1d0, org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0, config: {ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV1d0, org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV2d0, org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV1d0, org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV1d0, org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
```

And this the error message:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
Serialization trace:
id (org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferenceEdge)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:375)
CompletableFuture.java:375
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:1934)
CompletableFuture.java:1934
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.one(ResultSet.java:119)
ResultSet.java:119
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.hasNext(ResultSet.java:171)
ResultSet.java:171
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:178)
ResultSet.java:178
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:165)
ResultSet.java:165
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:140)
DriverRemoteTraversal.java:140
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:125)
DriverRemoteTraversal.java:125
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal.nextTraverser(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:106)
DriverRemoteTraversal.java:106
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:80)
RemoteStep.java:80
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:128)
AbstractStep.java:128
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:38)
AbstractStep.java:38
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.fill(Traversal.java:179)
Traversal.java:179
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.toList(Traversal.java:117)
Traversal.java:117
    at com.ibm.graph.App.main(App.java:25)
App.java:25
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your problem is in a mismatch of serializer configuration between driver and server. For the driver you do:

```
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0,
              config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

but for the server you have:

```
- { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, 
    config: { ioRegistries [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0, 
                            org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

You've omitted `TinkerIoRegistryV3d0` on the driver side. With `ioRegistries` the order in which the registries are added matters. So, you might have gotten lucky if you'd added `JanusGraphIoRegistry` first on the server and then accidentally omitted `TinkerIoRegistryV3d0` on the driver because the serializer registration identifiers would have aligned for JansuGraph.

Anyway, add `TinkerIoRegistryV3d0` to the driver configuration OR remove it from the server configuration and things should work. As a side note, you typically only need the `TinkerIoRegistryV3d0` if you're serializing TinkerGraph instances over the wire (e.g. using `subgraph()` step).